# Issue with numpy matrix multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to multiply two matrices of dimensions (17,2) by transposing one of the matrices

Here is example p1

```
    p1 = [[ 0.15520622 -0.92034567]
 [ 0.43294367 -1.05921439]
 [ 0.7569707  -1.15179354]
 [ 1.08099772 -1.15179354]
 [ 1.35873517 -0.96663524]
 [-1.51121847 -0.64260822]
 [-1.32606018 -0.87405609]
 [-1.00203315 -0.96663524]
 [-0.67800613 -0.96663524]
 [-0.3539791  -0.87405609]
 [ 0.89583942  1.02381648]
 [ 0.66439155  1.3478435 ]
 [ 0.3866541   1.48671223]
 [ 0.15520622  1.5330018 ]
 [-0.07624165  1.5330018 ]
 [-0.3539791   1.44042265]
 [-0.58542698  1.20897478]]
```

here is another example matrix p2

```
 p2 = [[ 0.20932473 -0.90029958]
 [ 0.53753779 -1.03849455]
 [ 0.88302521 -1.10759204]
 [ 1.24578701 -1.02122018]
 [ 1.47035383 -0.77937898]
 [-1.46628927 -0.69300713]
 [-1.29354556 -0.9521227 ]
 [-0.96533251 -1.03849455]
 [-0.63711946 -1.00394581]
 [-0.3089064  -0.90029958]
 [ 0.86575084  1.06897874]
 [ 0.55481216  1.37991742]
 [ 0.26114785  1.50083802]
 [ 0.03658102  1.51811239]
 [-0.1879858   1.50083802]
 [-0.46437574  1.37991742]
 [-0.74076568  1.08625311]]
```

I'm trying to multiply them using numpy

```
import numpy

print(p1.T * p2)
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,17) (17,2)
```

This is the expected matrix multiplication output

```
[[11.58117944  2.21072324]
 [-0.51754442 22.28728876]]
```

Where exactly am I going wrong

Comment: And what would the desired output look like? P.S. reduce example to 3 (as least as possible) rows.

Comment: The result should be a 2X2 something like this

Comment: [[ 0.99879867  0.04900222]
 [-0.04900222  0.99879867]]

Comment: Are you sure you need multiplication, I answered with `np.dot` but your result is not what you get with dot product.

Comment: I had a running code when I used p1.T * p2 before and it was working perfectly fine..When I'm reading p1 and p2 from JSON, I started getting the issue again. Still, your answer worked fine but would like to know why it is inconsistent

Comment: Updated the question with real values. I tried your answer but it isnt matching with the standalone that I wrote

Comment: How did you define `p1` and `p2` before?  With `np.matrix`?  How do you read them from `JSON`?  with `np.array`?  Star multiplication is different for the 2 classes of array.

Comment: I was getting p1 and p2 from np.matrix which was working, then converted it into list and saved it as json.. When I started reading it from JSON using np.array, this error occured

Comment: I tried printing p1 and p2 along with their dtype just before the star multiplication.. Both my standalone and json code are showing the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for a vague question. Initially, I was getting p1 and p2 values from numpy matrix. I later stored them in json file as list for optimization by using

> .tolist()

method and was reading it back as numpy array using

> numpy.array()

method which is apparently wrong..I changed my code to read the numpy array using

> numpy.matrix()

method which seems to solve the issue. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is done with `np.dot(p1.T,p2)`, because 
`A * B` means matrix elements-wise multiply.

Answer (score 0):

So you should use [np.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
p1.T.dot(p2)
```